# Add events to existing calendar with eventSources array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, fullcalendar

recently I was asked in my work to modify an existing module, the calendar, they want me to add filters to it, the events the calendar handles are evaluations, birthdays and announcements.

I have a drop-down menu that has the certain id when a user selects an option the calendar evaluations will disappear and bring only the evaluations from that selected id. my problem is that I can't bring the selected id evaluations because I don't know exactly how. The person who did this is no longer in the company and I have no way of contacting it.

This is how the calendar is created when the page loads:

```
      calendarDiv = $('#calendar')

  $(document).on 'click', '#create-button', (e) ->
    $(this).hide()

  $(document).on 'click', '#update-button', (e) ->
    $(this).hide()

  remove_hidden_modals()
  fetch_event()

  # page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
  date = new Date()
  d = date.getDate()
  m = date.getMonth()
  y = date.getFullYear()
  calendarDiv.fullCalendar
    dayNamesShort: ["D", "L", "M", "M", "J", "V", "S"]
    firstDay: 1
    monthNames: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
    buttonText:
      today: "Hoy"
    eventSources: [
      url: "/calendar/events/"
      className: "school"
    ,
      url: "/calendar/evaluations/"
      className: "evaluation"
    ,
      url: "/calendar/employees_birthdays/"
      className: "staff-birthday"
    ,
      url: "/calendar/students_birthdays/"
      className: "birthday"
    ]
    loading: (isCalendarLoading) ->
      if (isCalendarLoading)
        calendarDiv.find('.fc-header-center').append('#{loader_html}')
      else
        calendarDiv.find('.fc-header-center').find('.ajax-loader').remove()

    # put your options and callbacks here
    timeFormat: "h:mm t{ - h:mm t} "
    dragOpacity: "0.5"

    #http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/
    eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) ->
      event.ignoreTimeZone = true
      updateEvent event


    # http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/
    eventResize: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) ->
      updateEvent event
```

Now, when someone selects an option on the drop-down menu triggers this:

```
    $(document).ready ->
  selected_course = ''

  $('#school_courses').on 'change', ->
    selected_course = document.getElementById("school_courses")
    selected_course = selected_course.options[selected_course.selectedIndex].value
    allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

    userEventIds= [];
    has_new_events = false
    $.each allEvents, (index, value) ->

      if value.url  !=  undefined
        if value.url.search( 'evaluation_info' ) > 0
          userEventIds.push value.id
          has_new_events = true

    $.each userEventIds, (index, value) ->
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', value);
```

here I remove all the evaluations and I try to bring only the ones with the selected id. I was thinking if there's a way to do it with the event sources array, something like

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar('renderEvent',         eventSources: [
      url: "/calendar/evaluations/" + selected_course
      className: "evaluation"
    ])
```

but this doesn't work.

What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Your call to renderEvent makes no sense. You've misunderstood how fullCalendar gets events fed to it. You may be wanting this, I think: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/. Or possibly you can get away with this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ but defining the "data" option (as shown in the section titled "jQuery $.ajax options") to get the value of your ID from your dropdown. Then all you have to do when the dropdown "change" event happens is to call the "refetchEvents" method (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/)

Comment: Ok it worked, but now is creating a new calendar instead of rendering the events on the old one, looks like using the ".fullCalendar()" creates a new one... what can i do? @ADyson

Comment: yes it does. So put the eventsource info within your original calendar declaration, no need to create another one.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you make a pastie giving me an example? please, and sorry to bother you. @ADyson

Comment: above, you already did `calendarDiv.fullCalendar
    dayNamesShort: ["D", "L", "M", "M", "J", "V", "S"]...etc`. This is where you first declare the calendar, from what I can see. So you just put the eventSources as another option in there, instead of running .fullCalendar again later.